# Integrate Shopping Cart Wordpress with calculator

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I have a calculator at http://www.ledlightsforhome.co.uk/calculate-my-savings/
This calculates the total price and savings of LED lights. What I want to do is add a button that will redirect to the shopping cart page:  and automatically add the bulbs and its quantity selected in the calculators into the shopping cart. The product page is http://www.ledlightsforhome.co.uk/store-2/

The shopping cart now used is ecwid.
However if it is not possible to do this ecwid I will be able to use other plugin. Please help

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ecwid-shopping-cart/